# sending ajax form to jsp page

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, extjs

I have my ajax url placed as url:'save-form.jsp'. now how would i know that whether the form is submitted to jsp page or not. how can i check it from jsp end.

When i click on submit it does not even redirect to the jsp page.

```
id:'save-form',
el:'pagingJson-grid',
labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
url:'save-form.php',
```

I am using extJS

Comment: Have you tried opening the url in your browser (rather than with ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `save-form.php` by `save-form.jsp` or better, `saveFormServlet`. JSP is not really the right place to execute some business stuff.

To check if the request is successful, use a HTTP request tracker like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and to check if the business code is correctly executed, add some strategic logging statements to the code.